# Center span vertically

Tags: css

I've this code :

```css
a {
  background: #A9A9A9;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
a span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Center</span></a>
```

I want to center vertically the `span` into `a` who is in `position: absolute;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position:relative` to span and give `top:50%`

```css
a {
 background: #A9A9A9;
 display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: middle;
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
}

a span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0px, -50%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Center</span></a>
```

**Solution 2:**

use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`.

```css
a {
  background: #A9A9A9;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  display:table;
}
a span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Center</span></a>
```

Comment: Transform is not take cross platform compatibility :( , but interesting answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Great use case for flexbox. Just make sure you check vendor prefixes and broswer support:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
a {
 background: #A9A9A9;
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

a span {
  
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Center</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
 background: #A9A9A9;
 display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: middle;
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
}

a span {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: -8px; /* height/2 */ 
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Center</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

changes in style may help you

```
 a {
    background: #A9A9A9;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}

a span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Center</span></a>
```